# How can I press a key inside javascript, chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension and I want to simulate that the user presses a button on his keyboard. I am using javascript.

Here is my current code:

```
document.getElementsByName("something")[0].select(); // I select the element an now I want to press a key for example 'b'
```

Comment: Search for [stackoverflow javascript simulate press key](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+javascript+simulate+press+key), there are lots of examples. Use them inside a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: @wOxxOm I am trying to find an answer for 4 hours and i can't find any. Can you help me to find one? I would really appreciate that.

Comment: This is weird because if you open the first link I gave it's inside the first result of the search, which shouldn't have taken more than a few seconds.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have already tried those and it doesn't work.

Comment: Assuming that's true, it means we won't be able to help you without seeing more of the context, or [MCVE](/help/mcve), which should include a reproducible test case on a real URL or inside a subset HTML that reproduces the problem.